Natural, AI-based TTS for Android?
Given that Android has a pluggable text-to-speech functionality, I'd like to add one of the most natural AI TTS to my system. I was very impressed when I heard what OpenAI can do, but I don't know how to let all applications use it for speech synthesis. Is there an app that enables that? Or any other AI-based TTS service?
I need it to support Polish language and sound as natural as possible because one of the applications will be to read books for me. I'm OK with paid services, but it's very important to me that it's exposed through the Android's TTS functionality, as opposed to being a separate service.
